# Ни в чём (не)виновный — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, прилагательные, частица-не

Как правильно пишется фраза ***ни в чём (не)виновный***?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь - раздельно. Идет речь об отрицании виновности, а не о каком-то новом качестве. Иначе было бы "невиновный *во всем*".

Вообще, когда есть усилительная частица "ни" должно быть и самостоятельное "не" которое она усиливает. Исключение возможны, но крайне редки, это особый стиль какой-то авторский.

Comment: Интересно, а если подобное определение без "НЕ" не употребляется? Получается, что в этом случае усилительное "НИ" вообще невозможно?

Comment: Верно, невозможно. Нельзя сказать "ни в чём нелепый". Можно лишь сказать "нелепый во всём".

Answer (score 4):

Ни в чем не виновный.

Это **усиление отрицание**, стандартная конструкция, поэтому вряд ли слитное написание будет одобрено.

Пример:

И он поймет, что если уж я, **ни в чем не виновный**, решил платить, то ему, по самые уши замазанному, тоже придется это сделать. [Александра Маринина. Мужские игры (1997)]